# Jquery | How to split textarea @ on buttun click?

Tags: jquery

I want to cut the email @ by clicking on the button,

To appear like that: test

http://jsfiddle.net/7as7y/1376/

```
<textarea id="txtList" placeholder="" style="color:black">test@gmail.com</textarea>
<input id="email" style="" value="Split" type="button">

(function(){
$("#email").on('click', function(e){
$("#txtList").val($("#txtList").val().split("@"));
});
});

Without function:
//var input = "test@gmail.com";
//var arr = input.split("@");
//alert(arr[0]);
```

Comment: this what you want?http://jsfiddle.net/7as7y/1377/  Please note you didn't include jquery in your example and you were missing `[0]`

Comment: First get current value to variable, then split it and after that set the new value

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes, it was fast. thank you! write it as answer too so i can vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you forgot to include `jQuery` in your example.

Second, you are missing `[0]` at the end of `.split("@")`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#email").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#txtList").val($("#txtList").val().split("@")[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtList" placeholder="" style="color:black">test@gmail.com</textarea>
<input id="email" style="" value="Split" type="button">
```

Comment: I also forgot $ ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your event on simple auto-execution so it's possible that you put `.on` on non-existing element. Move to `domready` or change to `$(document).on('click', '#email')`

---

When you `.split()` your value, you get array. And obvious you can't assign input value to be array. Use `[0]` to select only first element from this array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#email").on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($("#txtList").val().split("@"))
    $("#txtList").val($("#txtList").val().split("@")[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtList" placeholder="" style="color:black">test@gmail.com</textarea>
<input id="email" style="" value="Split" type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery library in your file and also instead of .on you can use .click method directly.
Find the working solution below.

```js
$("#email").click(function(e) {
  $("#txtList").val($("#txtList").val().split("@"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtList" placeholder="" style="color:black">test@gmail.com</textarea>
<input id="email" style="" value="Split" type="button">
```

Comment: I don't think the op wants too replace @ with `,` as your example does

Comment: as per question "I want to cut the email @ by clicking on the button,

", i have just split it up. @mosibo, i f you want to get the first part of splitted input, you can use $("#txtList").val().split("@")[0]